# Mathematica computes too slowly at the start of a session

Tags: performance-tuning

Everyone, I'm a Mathematica new user. I find it a problem that, when I start a new Mathematica session, it executes too slowly for the first command (say, "1+1", it may take a few seconds before it gives the "2").

Can you help me resolve the problem? (My Mathematica is running on OS X 10.10)

Comment: This is normal. The front-end is just that, and until you do something that requires a kernel, there are none. The first operation you do that needs a kernel starts the kernel(s), this takes a moment.

Comment: See [Using a Notebook Interface](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingANotebookInterface.html)

Comment: I'd say it is a valid question. And definitely not easy to find in docs :)

Comment: It has been this way for 25+ years and although I guess you could come up with a method to reduce the start-up time for the first question with the second or so that it takes to fire up a kernel, it would involve increasing the initial start-up time of Mathematica by about the same amount. So there's zero gain. I'd say: try to live with this very minor inconvenience.

Comment: [Your first calculation will take longer than subsequent calculations because the Wolfram Language kernel has to start up.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/YourFirstWolframLanguageCalculations.html) - first few lines of the first tutorials...